# Is there a way to access variables inside of a .xcconfigfile from the terminal?

Tags: xcode, bash, terminal, xcconfig

I have an .xcconfig file that I want to access via the terminal to access variables in the file. Is there a command or is there some way to do this? For example I have a variable called Build_Code = 1234. How would I access that?

Answer (score 2):

Create a script to read the value of a variable.

**Ex: .xconfig**

```
var1 = value1
var2 = value2
```

**get_value.bash**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# get_value.bash <file> <variable>
#
usage()
{
    echo "Usage: get_value.bash <file> <variable>"
    exit 1
}

#################################################

# Arguments
if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]
then
    file="$1"
    var="$2"
else
    usage
fi

# Check if the file exists
if [[ ! -f "$file" ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: file $file does not exist."
    exit 2
fi

# Get the variable's value
grep -w "$var" "$file" | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d ' '
```

- This simple version assumes the format of the lines is `VARIABLE\s*=\s*VALUE`.
- The `tr` is to remove spaces around the value.
- The VALUE cannot contain spaces.
- The `<file>` argument could be hard coded if you will only ever check `.xconfig`

Many other solutions could be conceived, depending on the exact requirements, but this does the basic need you put in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If it's part of an Xcode project, you can run `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings` to see a list of the system defaults, plus what is in the default target's config values with variables replaced by values).  You can also pass `-json` to get the results as a json file.   For an explicit file, you can use the `-xcconfig <path>` argument as well.  If in a project, it shows that file, then the project.  If standalone, it just shows the values in that file.  Unfortunately, `-json` does not seem to work when using that option.  You would still have to parse the result a bit, but those values are more normalized, with comments stripped, from the original xcconfig.  includes are processed but variables are not replaced in the `-xcconfig` mode.